# ng2 Change Detection - what could cause 'ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick()' to be called periodically

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-changedetection

I assume  'ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick()' in @angular/core is needed to update the DOM properly in angular 2 RC4, (and properly earlier version as well)

In an angular 2 hybrid setup, created from 5 min quickstart example (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), this method is called, but it seems it is only called finite amount of times initially.

I am having an issue with change detection in a hybrid setup (ng1 & ng2 working together using upgradeAdapter) and only in certain servers. This leads me to dig deep into change detection.

**My question is**: what could cause 'ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick()' to be called periodically? It seems that in the case where my component works, this method is called periodically, NOT finite amount of time like the 5 min quickstart. And maybe I will need to force that to ensure it works stably.

Sorry there is no plunker as I haven't been able to generated a simplified version of my current situation

Thanks!

Comment: To the simplest, in Angular2, `ApplicationRef.tick` function will be called when an asynchronous event (e.g. button click, server returns response) arises within its context (means Angular2 will not care about some random button outside of it). If your ng1 setup is within ng2's `zone`, it may disrupt ng2 change detection.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes,  I suspect my problem could be something with upgradeAdapter, where it doesn't manage ng2 change detection and ng1 digest cycle properly for some reasons ... any idea on which piece of codes that are in charge of doing this management...Update: it wasn't the 5 min quick start i was talking about. To be correct, it is this this hybrid setup (plnkr.co/edit/ydzQyjDAKCtcvDE8hNRo?p=preview), which is created from the 5 min quickstart, and it only called tick() finite amount of times initially.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out there was bug with ng2 upgrade adapter RC.4 -> 2.0.1 final.

In `upgrade_adapter.ts`:

```
ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe({
  next: (_: any) => ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => rootScope.$evalAsync())
});
```

If that is changed to:

```
ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe({
  next: (_: any) => ngZone.run(() => rootScope.$evalAsync())
});
```

Change detection seems to work.

One drawback is: this will re-introduce the infinite `$rootScope.$digest` (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6385)